# How to append new node in xml with Python?

Tags: xml, lxml

The objective was to append a node within the node `testcases` using the `lxml` append function.

However, the compiler return the following error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

But, append the new node into the super node such as `question` does not produce any error. But as expected, this does not produce the intended output.

May I know how to address this issue?

The code to reproduce the above issue is

```
from lxml import etree
    
tree = etree.parse("d_xml.xml")

d='<testcase testtype="0" useasexample="0" hiderestiffail="0" mark="1.0000000" > <testcode> <text>print(solve(' \
  'read_file("file_2.txt")))</text> </testcode><stdin><text></text></stdin><expected><text>status_2</text></expected' \
  '><extra><text></text></extra><display><text>SHOW</text> </display></testcase>'
# contentnav = tree.find("question")
contentnav = tree.find("testcases")
contentnav.append(etree.XML(d))
print(etree.tostring(tree))
tree.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True,   encoding="utf-8")
```

The `d_xml.xml` content is a below or downloadable via the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1_y7dH5P66gIxrUnSwEUgsmjFJEXwvz/view?usp=sharing)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz>
  <!-- question: 0  -->
  <!-- question: 6675757  -->
  <question type="coderunner">
    <name>
      <text>test_code_runner</text>
    </name>
    <questiontext format="html">
      <text><![CDATA[<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">ex_test<br></p>]]></text>
    </questiontext>
    <generalfeedback format="html">
      <text></text>
    </generalfeedback>
    <giveupallowed>0</giveupallowed>
    <prototypeextra></prototypeextra>
    <testcases>
      <testcase testtype="0" useasexample="0" hiderestiffail="0" mark="1.0000000">
        <testcode>
          <text>print(solve(read_file('file_1.txt')))</text>
        </testcode>
        <stdin>
          <text></text>
        </stdin>
        <expected>
          <text>status_1</text>
        </expected>
        <extra>
          <text></text>
        </extra>
        <display>
          <text>SHOW</text>
        </display>
      </testcase>


      <file name="fmlie.cpp" path="/" encoding="base64">aW1wb3J0IHJhbmRvbH</file>
      <file name="idfile.txt" path="/" encoding="base64">TnVA2DQoyICg==</file>
    </testcases>
  </question>

</quiz>
```

The expected output is as below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz>
  <!-- question: 0  -->
  <!-- question: 6675757  -->
  <question type="coderunner">
    <name>
      <text>test_code_runner</text>
    </name>
    <questiontext format="html">
      <text><![CDATA[<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">ex_test<br></p>]]></text>
    </questiontext>
    <generalfeedback format="html">
      <text></text>
    </generalfeedback>
    <giveupallowed>0</giveupallowed>
    <prototypeextra></prototypeextra>
    <testcases>
      <testcase testtype="0" useasexample="0" hiderestiffail="0" mark="1.0000000">
        <testcode>
          <text>print(solve(read_file('file_1.txt')))</text>
        </testcode>
        <stdin>
          <text></text>
        </stdin>
        <expected>
          <text>status_1</text>
        </expected>
        <extra>
          <text></text>
        </extra>
        <display>
          <text>SHOW</text>
        </display>
      </testcase>
      <testcases>
        <testcase testtype="0" useasexample="0" hiderestiffail="0" mark="1.0000000">
          <testcode>
            <text>print(solve(read_file('file_2.txt')))</text>
          </testcode>
          <stdin>
            <text></text>
          </stdin>
          <expected>
            <text>status_2</text>
          </expected>
          <extra>
            <text></text>
          </extra>
          <display>
            <text>SHOW</text>
          </display>
        </testcase>


        <file name="fmlie.cpp" path="/" encoding="base64">aW1wb3J0IHJhbmRvbH</file>
        <file name="idfile.txt" path="/" encoding="base64">TnVA2DQoyICg==</file>
      </testcases>
  </question>

</quiz>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there; try:

```
d=etree.fromstring('<testcase testtype="0" useasexample="0" hiderestiffail="0" mark="1.0000000" > <testcode> <text>print(solve(' \
  'read_file("file_2.txt")))</text> </testcode><stdin><text></text></stdin><expected><text>status_2</text></expected' \
  '><extra><text></text></extra><display><text>SHOW</text> </display></testcase>')

dest = tree.xpath('//question//testcases//testcase')[-1]
#this makes sure d is inserted as the last testcase

dest.addnext(d)
print(etree.tostring(tree).decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

`find()` method finds the [first child of the context element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements), in this case, root element. But `testcases` is not a direct child so it returns None.

Two solutions:
Find `question` and then `testcases` out of it.

```
contentnav = doc.find("question").find("testcases")
```

Use Xpath

```
contentnav = doc.xpath("//testcases")[0]
```